# Reload Customer Admin Tab Via Ajax

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, ajax

Within the customer area of admin I have created a wishlist manager where i can add products to a wishlist on behalf of a customer. This also has a grid showing the customers wishlist items however this becomes out of date when products are added.

How can i trigger a reload of the custom tab that i have created?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is not the Magento way but is my solution for now and works fine for me:

```
function reloadtab() {
    $.ajax({
                type        : 'GET', 
                url         : '<?php echo $this->getTabUrl(); ?>' 
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $(".admin__scope-old").html(data);
            });
};
```

Please post if there is a better magento way of doing this and will accept this answer.

**Update**

One issue i have so far is that this page does have a modal however firing it causes the below error:

```
jquery.js:253 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'openModal'
```

Adding `$(".admin__scope-old")).trigger('contentUpdated');` does not seem to fix the issue but i can just reinitialise the modal in the success function for now.

Comment: Hello did you got more appropriate method for this issue?Also, could you please show how did you reinitialize the modal?

Comment: Sorry so far just left it as is as worked fine and no one has posted a better answer. I just added the same code for initialising within the done function. Was all a bit messy really.